# Should I use a set to prevent items being added more than once to the collection by mistake?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Please see the code below:

```
public class Customer
{
    private readonly IHashSet<Order> _orders = new Set<Order>();

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders 
    {
        get { foreach (var order in _orders) yield return order; }
    }

    internal void AddOrder(Order order)
    {
        _orders.Add(order);
    }
}
```

I am trying to decide whether the `_orders` property should be a `List` (which I would normally use) or a `Set`.  The only reason a duplicate order would be added is if the client code added a duplicate by mistake.  Does that warrant the use of a `Set`? Is that a valid use case for a `Set`?

Comment: Seems like a valid reason to use a set. You've already got a set - you might want to have your `AddOrder` method return a bool (added) or throw if the item already exists. Incidentally, why do you `yield return` the items in `_orders` instead of just returning `_orders` in `Orders`?

Comment: If duplicate can only be added by mistake - consider still using set but check return value of Add and if false - throw exception and not silently ignore.

Comment: @Evk, an item could be added to any collection by mistake and despite this - Sets are not always used.  I am trying to understand when a set should be used.

Comment: Well when it fits your requirements. Order is not important, duplicates are not allowed, no need for random access (doesn't make sense anyway for unordered collection), need to check for existance in constant time. For example, your `Orders` can, in theory (in practice I doubt that) return orders in different order every time you access it.

Comment: One case when using set can heavily degrade performance is when you transform a large (think thousands of items) set with some mapper function. Because for each transformed element it would enforce uniquiness. So in this case it may be way faster to make a list from the set, then make it set again, after transformation is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this is a valid use case, if duplicate orders are not allowed.

Since you expose `IEnumerable<Order>` instead of `IList<Order>` you don't seem to be interested in keeping the insertion order, or let the caller use it like a list or array. So a `HashSet<T>` is perfect here. The database is the best place to ensure that no duplicates are added, but it's not wrong to check that also at client-side. On this way you can handle bugs early and report them in your logs.

```
public class Customer
{
    private readonly HashSet<Order> _orders = new HashSet<Order>();

    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders => _orders;

    // ...

    internal void AddOrder(Order order)
    {
        _orders.Add(order);
    }
}
```

Note that you should override `Equals`+`GetHasCode` in `Order`, implement `IEquatable<Order>` or pass a custom `IEquatable<Comparer>` to the [`HashSet` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359100(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: choice of data structure and choice of method of business rule enforcement should not interfere. if they fit by chance, like here, then fine. Be aware that you will get no duplicate exception from the set, as `HashSet` does not throw but uses [AddIfNotPresent](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,958) internally.

Comment: Are there any limitations to using sets? I see lists being used all the time when I think a HashSet would be better - because duplicates should not be added.

Comment: @w0051977: yes, you can't access an item via index, it's an unordered collection. But it's more efficient in lookups. If the caller needs a list he could use `List<Order> orders = customer.Orders.ToList()`.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter is correct.  It returns false.  It does not throw an exception.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter would you suggest using a Set in this case or just "blame" it on someone else if they add a duplicate by mistake?

Comment: @w0051977: depends on how important it is to store the order in which they were added. In general this is the right place to use a set if no duplicate orders should be added.

Comment: @dlatikay, can you provide an example where choice of business rule enforcement and data structure interfere?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, I agree with your last comment.  However, the only reason a duplicate order would be added is if a developer did it by mistake (because of a bug) i.e. all orders have a unique identity in the database.  Is this still a valid use case?

Comment: @w0051977: it still depends on how important the insertion-order is, if that is not relevant you should use a set because that is the exact type that matches your unique index constraint in database. But of course you could also use a `List<Order>` and handle the `SqlException`, f.e(SQL-Server). `catch (SqlException ex) when (new[] {2627, 2601}.Contains(ex.ErrorCode)){ duplicateFound=true; }`.

Comment: @w0051977 what I'm trying to say is that the data structure you choose should not dictate how you handle duplicates. you will want a consistent way of reacting to invalid uses of your library methods. If that is going to be "silently ignore attempts to add items that have already been added", and `HashSet` does that just right, then go ahead.

Comment: @w0051977: Since you expose `IEnumerable<Order>` instead of `IList<Order>` you don't seem to be interested in keeping the insertion order, or let the caller use it like a list or array. So a `HashSet<T>` is perfect here. The database is the best place to ensure that no duplicates are added, but it's not wrong to check that also at client-side. On this way you can handle bugs early and report them in your logs.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, are ienumerables always iterated in a random order regardless of what is being iterated i.e. list, hashset etc? Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977 no, how they are enumerated is determined by their GetEnumerator method. A list uses a different way than a HashSet or dictionary of course.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, thanks.  In that case could you explain what you mean by: "Since you expose IEnumerable<Order> instead of IList<Order> you don't seem to be interested in keeping the insertion order"

Comment: @w0051977 the caller of your class doesn't need to know what type it actually is. You return IEnumerable<T>. He could cast it but he should not do that because you are free to change the internal type if you want. So you guarantee not a list which can be accessed by index but just IEnunerable. The type is still a HashSet but that's not the contract

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, I think you are saying that the caller could call either ToList or ToHashSet.  If he/she runs ToHashSet then order is not guaranteed.  Is that right?

Comment: @w0051977 there's no ToHashset. You're confusing things. ToList is a linq method that creates a new list from anything that implements IEnumerable<T>. I mean the caller can cast what your property returns to HashSet<T> if he knows what it actually is. But he shouldn't do because you return IEnumerable<T> and are free to change your implementation tomorrow to use a Order[] if you wanted. That would break his code, but it's his fault not yours. If you declare an instance as one of its base types(like a HashSet as IEnumerable) you don't change the real type.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense.  +1.  Finally, is it bad practice for a hashset to silently fail adding an item to itself? Notice that AddOrder returns void meaning the caller is unaware that it has failed.

Comment: @w0051977 depends on if the caller needs to know the information if the order already existed. Then replace void with bool and return the value which  HashSet.Add returned. But i think in this case you have two options: 1) fail with a meaningful exception after you've logged it. 2) log this information but don't throw an exception. You should also add a Debug.Assert. Add must return true. On this way you should be able to detect bugs early

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, I am going back through the questions I have not accepted.  Before I accept - I watched this video, which states that Entities should not have equality: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRCOKKUSp9s.  Therefore is it best to use an IEqualityComparer for Hashsets in the context of DDD meaning referential equality is used by default when calling .equals?  +1

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged your question with domain-driven-design tag, so the answer should be given in this context.

There is a rule in DDD called "make explicit what is implicit". If you don't want to have duplicates in your orders, in my opinion you should add some simple code that makes this rule explicit. It can be just a simple `vetoIfOrderIsDupicated` private method or something similar. It will give you a chance to communicate your team mates (or even you in the future) that there is a rule which should not be broken. If you just change this collection to Set, it doesn't carry any information **WHY** this is a Set. In the future someone from your team (or you personally) will refactor this code for example from performance perspective and will change Set to some high performance List, but will loose the rule.

So answering your question: I recommend to make the rule explicit. And collection can be Set if you want.

Additionally and not correlated to question, I don't know your domain, but it seems to me, that Order is another Aggregate Root. If yes, you shouldn't reference both Aggregate Roots. Instead you should reference IDs of AggR. So `_orders` should be collection of `OrderID`.